# Unable to resize image and maintain transparency

Tags: java, image-processing

The below code resizes an image.  Unfortunately the image which is a vertical image has black bars on the sides.  It looks as though the transparent, or blank space is being filled with black.  I've tried setting the background color to white, and using alphaRGB but can't seem to shake it.

```
    OrderProductAssetEntity orderProductAssetEntity = productAssets.get(jobUnitEntity.getId());
    File asset = OrderProductAssetService.getAssetFile(orderProductAssetEntity);
    if (asset.exists()) {
        //resize the asset to a smaller size
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(asset), 0, 0, width, height, null);
        g.dispose();

        jobUnitImages.put(orderProductAssetEntity.getOriginalLocation(), new PDJpeg(document, resizedImage));
    } else {
        jobUnitImages.put(orderProductAssetEntity.getOriginalLocation(), null);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you need transparency, `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` won't work, you'll need `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`. Not sure if you already tried it, just want to be clear.

Second, this line:

```
g.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

...does only set the *current background color* for the graphics context. It does *not* fill the background with that color. For that, you'll need to do `g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)` as well.  But I usually prefer to use `g.setColor(...)` and `g.fillRect(...)` instead to avoid confusion.

Or, if you like, you can also use the `drawImage` method that takes a `Color` as the second last parameter like this:

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, Color.WHITE, null);
```

EDIT:

Third, the class name `PDJpeg` implies that the image is later stored as JPEG, so you will probably lose transparency anyway. So the best is probably to stick with `TYPE_INT_RGB`, and fill the background with the right color (and do it the right way ;-).

Comment: Perfect!  I used `g.drawImage(...)`  Thanks!!